# Передача параметров в компонет Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

Не могу придумать как добиться следующего:

В компонент Blazor необходимо передать коллекцию(или массив) параметров.
Передаваемые параметры — компоненты Blazor.
Коллекцию параметров необходимо передать в виде вложенного тега.
Необходима возможность вызова рендеринга каждого переданного параметра-компонента по отдельности.

То-есть хочу приблизительно такого:

```html
<MyComponent>
  <ParameterCollection>
    <MyParameterComponent1>Caption1</MyParameterComponent1>
    <MyParameterComponent2>Caption2</MyParameterComponent2>
    <MyParameterComponent3>Caption3</MyParameterComponent3>
  </ParameterCollection>
</MyComponent>
```

Код MyComponent:

```
@code{
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment[] ParameterCollection {get; set;} //Ошибка времени выполнения
}
```

То что я хочу получить, уже видимо реализовано здесь [коммерческий компонент](https://demos.telerik.com/blazor-ui/grid/overview) (выберите вкладку VIEW SOURCE).
В параметр GridColumns передается коллекция компонентов GridColumn. Тточнее, как я думаю — коллекция соответствующих им RenderFragment.
Вопрос — как это сделано?

Answer (score 0):

В проекте Blazorise есть аналогичный компонент - https://blazorise.com/docs/components/grid/
В отличие от коммерческого аналога, там вы можете посмотреть исходный код компонентов, строка принимающая столбцы:
https://github.com/stsrki/Blazorise/blob/e07281fc71a0f6788cad82f78bd75e0d21151536/Source/Extensions/Blazorise.DataGrid/_DataGridRow.razor.cs#L172